# Opening Aura Component by URL opens utility bar as well

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I'm trying to open a new browser popup that loads an AURA component or Flexipage directly by their URL from a page that has a utility bar.

I am able to do this, but after it is loaded, the utility bar also automatically loads on those pages and this behavior is undesirable to me.

Is there a way to prevent the utility bar from automatically loading when opening these components directly in a pop out?

I can't close the utility bar from the Aura component because it is not part of that component.